# How to hide SwiftUI list divider

Tags: swiftui, ios13

I'm trying to hide the divider between cells in a List, but looks like there is no way to do it, based on Apple´s documentation.

Any idea for how to do it?

Comment: That looks like a good solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## iOS 15:

This year Apple introduced a new modifier `.listRowSeparator` that can be used to style the separators. you can pass `.hidden` to hide it:

```
List {
    ForEach(items, id:\.self) { 
        Text("Row \($0)")
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    }
}
```

---

## iOS 14

In iOS 14, you may consider using `LazyVStack` instead of list for this:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach((1...100), id: \.self) {
           Text("Placeholder \($0)")
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `LazyVStack` is lazy and doesn't render all rows all the time. So they are very performant and suggested by Apple itself in WWDC 2020.

---

## iOS 13

There is a `UITableView` behind SwiftUI's `List` for iOS. So to remove

### Extra separators (below the list):

you need a `tableFooterView` and to remove

### All separators (including the actual ones):

you need `separatorStyle` to be `.none`

```
init() {
    // To remove only extra separators below the list:
    UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()

    // To remove all separators including the actual ones:
    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
}

var body: some View {
    List {
        Text("Item 1")
        Text("Item 2")
        Text("Item 3")
    }
}
```

Comment: Friendly reminder: apply `.listRowSeparator(.hidden)` to each _element_ in the `List` – not to the `List` itself, because that won't do anything.